# Kendo Grids ClientTemplate for ForeignKey column not displaying chosen value?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using `MVC`, I am trying to implement `inline-editing` of a **Kendo Grid** using a `Foreign Key Column`...which should display & save a chosen value from it's relevant `ComboBox`.

Editing works...but it doesn't display the chosen value upon UPDATING the row.

- What am I doing wrong?

**MY VIEW CONTROL LOOKS LIKE:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbus>()
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RTUDeviceId)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Register)
                      .Title("Register")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Description)
                      .Title("Description")
                      .Width(100);
                  columns.ForeignKey(x => x.DataUnitId, Model.DataUnits, "Id", "DataUnitName")
                      .ClientTemplate((@Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                          .BindTo(Model.DataUnits)
                          .Name("ddlDataUnits_#=Id#")
                          .DataValueField("Id")
                          .DataTextField("DataUnitName")
                          .ToClientTemplate()).ToHtmlString())
                      .Title("Units")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.ForeignKey(x => x.DataTypeId, Model.DataTypes, "Id", "DataTypeName")
                      .Title("Data Type")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.DataTypeSize)
                      .Title("ASCII (size)")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(100);
              })
              .Name("gridCustomRegisterModbus")
              .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
              .Sortable()
              .Scrollable()
              .BindTo(Model.RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbuses)
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                                  .ServerOperation(true)
                                                  .PageSize(50)
                                                  .Model(model => { model.Id(m => m.Id); })
                                                  .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  )
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "", @style = "height: 400px;" }))
```

**MY ACTION LOOKS LIKE:**
Yes, it calls the action...but the DataUnitId is NULL.  So, I am guessing I need the client template for that part...but that isn't working.

```
public class CustomRegisterModbusController : BaseController
{
    #region <Actions>

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbus entity)
    {
        // It makes the call to CREATE...but the value of the ID is null

        return Json(new[] { entity }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbus entity)
    {
        // Do awesome stuff
        return Json(new[] { entity }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbus entity)
    {
        // Do awesome stuff
        return Json(new[] { entity }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your update action return the updated model in Json?

Comment: please see updates...

Comment: So does your awesome stuff repopulate the `entity.DataUnits` collection on return?

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes...and the ACTION in the posted code shows that.  Please read the comment for CREATE...the DataUnitId is NULL

Comment: Try setting `ValuePrimitive(true)`. https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-edit-template-mvc-combobox

Comment: @SteveGreene ValuePrimitive(true) Doesn't work.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but here it is...

- I needed a client-side method to handle Grid.Save
- This method would sets any chosen `DROP DOWN LIST` value into the model

I tried all kinds of other posted solutions...this is the ONLY thing that worked.

**THE FINAL RAZOR MARKUP LOOKS LIKE:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbus>()
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RTUDeviceId)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Register)
                      .Title("Register")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Description)
                      .Title("Description")
                      .Width(100);
                  columns.ForeignKey(x => x.DataUnitId, Model.DataUnits, "Id", "DataUnitName")
                      .Title("Units")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.ForeignKey(x => x.DataTypeId, Model.DataTypes, "Id", "DataTypeName")
                      .Title("Data Type")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.DataTypeSize)
                      .Title("ASCII (size)")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(100);
              })
              .Name("gridCustomRegisterModbus")
              .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
              .Sortable()
              .Scrollable()
              .BindTo(Model.RTUDeviceCustomRegisterModbuses)
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                                  .ServerOperation(true)
                                                  .PageSize(50)
                                                  .Model(model => { model.Id(m => m.Id); })
                                                  .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "CustomRegisterModbus", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  )
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "", @style = "height: 400px;" }))
```

**THE JAVASCRIPT METHOD LOOKS LIKE:** 
Of course, you will probably put the method in your own 'controller' class

If you use Razor to bind to the GRIDS event...

```
.Events(events => events.Save("onSave"))
```

If you use a Custom JavaScript Controller to bind the event...

```
// Instances
var grid = $('#mygrid').data('kendoGrid');

// Bindings
grid.bind('save', onSave);

// Of course you would point to a custom Object
function onSave(e) {

    var model = e.model;
    var ddl = null;
    var text = null;

    // DataUnits
    ddl = $(e.container.find('[data-role=dropdownlist]')[0]).data('kendoDropDownList');
    text = ddl.value();

    if (text !== null && text.length > 0) {
        //model.DataUnitId = 0;
        model.set('DataUnitId', text);
    }

    // DataTypes
    ddl = $(e.container.find('[data-role=dropdownlist]')[1]).data('kendoDropDownList');
    text = ddl.value();

    if (text !== null && text.length > 0) {
        //model.DataTypeId = 0;
        model.set('DataTypeId', text);
    }
}
```